# Can't change font in XCode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, label

Within XCode 6.1.1 I'm unable to change the font on my label within my storyboard.   I can set 'Text' to either 'Plain' or 'Attributed', but then [T] next to Helevetica Neue 17.0 appears grayed out, and it does not do anything when I click it.   This happens in all of my projects.

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh5q4.png

Thank you!

Edit:  Unfortunately none of the answers below have answered my question yet.  The [T] is unclickable.. it is grayed out so I can't change the Font to custom under there.  And while I could go in and enter code to change the font, I would prefer to do it through the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was driving me crazy - your workaround works for the normal storyboard, but not for the Watch storyboard which has a custom fonts popup.

I finally found this page:
https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/4109

It's a bug with using Synergy - I connected a USB mouse to my Mac and when I click the font "T" icon with the USB mouse, it works!!!!

Comment: Thank you!  I am using Synergy and never would have thought it would have been that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to first select a syntax category in the detail area. You can press CMD+A to select all categories. Then you can click the "T" and select a new font.

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-fonts_and_colors_preferences_help/Recipe.html

Answer (score 0):

In the "font", change "system" to "custom”

Answer (score 0):

You can set font for labels in two ways- programmatically and in storyboard.

In your storyboard, you need to click the little T and then select the wanted font.

In your code, assuming you already set the appropriate IBOutlets, you can use something like

```
[self.theTextLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tap on the "T" sign next to the already assigned font, then change "system" to "custom”. Once the settings are on custom the font can be changed as well as it's weight (ie. light, bold...)

Answer (score 0):

I did find a workaround...  I can bring up the font menu by crtl-shift-opt-T and change the font there and changes I make are reflected on the page... but the [T] is still still grayed out for some reason.